# ₹ Symboles not supporting sales invioce pdf in magento 2.1.5

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have Magento 2.1.5 and that are not supporting ₹ symbols when we generate sales invoices. That pdf not showing ₹ symbols. Please check the screenshot.
screenshot: **https://prnt.sc/r0qi58**

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to extend the below file in your custom module to set the supportable font for the INR currency symbol.

> Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php

You can use [this](https://github.com/gunjali-agarwal/magento) already created module for order invoice pdf INR symbol change.

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
Stores-> Currency Symbols -> Uncheck Standard Symbol ->  Typed required symbol ->  ₹ -> Save
```

Refresh cache